# Data mismatch in Transactional replication with updatable subscription

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

Replication champs,

I have a Transactional replication with updatable subscription setup having 1 publisher and 3 subscribers. All the servers are SQL 2008 and have conflict resolution policy set as subscriber wins. Of late, I have been observing data mismatch for few tables. However replication is running fine without any issue. I am trying to understand what could have caused this issue and how it could be avoided in future.

Does anybody have any idea regarding this? Also is it possible to reproduce this scenario? Let me know if you need any further details.

Comment: Can someone please share his views?